# AngularJS - Add a drop down menu feature into a HTML table using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I would like to add a feature (which is a drop down menu into an image icon inside a table.
Here is the code description:

```
<HTML>
<!--Table-->
<div id="tableStructure"...>
   <table...>
      <thread>
         <tr><td class="people"></td></tr></thread></table>
...
</HTML>
```

Here is the controller (script)

```
$scope.buildtable = function() {
...
       $(".people", row).html("<img src='" + person.imageURL + "'/>");

...
```

So, on the table, each row would display an image icon, my question is how to add a dropdown menu when you click onto the icon.
My menu would look like this:

```
<div ng-controller="Controller">
   <li> List 1 </li>
   ...
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I'm not familiar with AngularJS.

I felt like funny when I saw your code, because you use AngularJS, but literally you use '.html()', which is jQuery method. There's no bind at all.

Personally, I think there's no problem you use both 'jQuery' and 'AngularJS', if it's organized.
I came up with the two ideas.
1.Use the same array using the filter.

```
<!-- table(when the img is clicked, you update its state.  -->
<tr ng-repeat="people in peopleList">
  <td>{{people.name}}</td>
  <td><img ng-src="{{people.imageUrl}}" ng-click="imgClick($index)"/></td>
</tr>

<!-- list(use the same array using filter) -->
<li ng-repeat="people in peopleList | filter : {state : '1'}">
  <img ng-src="{{people.imageUrl}}" />
</li>
```

2.Prepare the data for the list.

```
 <!-- table(when the img is clicked, you push its data to listItems.  -->
<tr ng-repeat="people in peopleList">
  <td>{{people.name}}</td>
  <td><img ng-src="{{people.imageUrl}}" ng-click="imgClick($index)"/></td>
</tr>

<!-- list -->
<li ng-repeat="item in listItems">
  <img ng-src="{{item.imageUrl}}" />
</li>
```

[Here's a super rough example.](http://jsfiddle.net/f9hg17ks/)

**UPDATED**
Whoops... Maybe I was misunderstood.
You **want to** use the normal HTML table(created By jQuery.html()).
In that case, you can use this code.

```
// called when the img is clicked
$(".table").on("click", ".people-image", function() {
    // Get the scope(you need to select which has ng-controller).
    var $scope = angular.element($('#your-app-controller')).scope();
    // Add img url.
    $scope.listItems.push({ imageUrl : $(this).attr("src") });
    // Apply it to view. (It seems this is bad practice, though.)
    $scope.$apply();
});
```

[Here's an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/j8eu6vdt/)